# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key studid'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I add a studid referance in another table

when I store the studid then give the error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key studid'

HomeController.cs

```
        private readonly dbstuudEntities dbstud;

        public HomeController()
        {
            dbstud = new dbstuudEntities();
        }

        public ActionResult BlogCreate()
        {         
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BlogCreate(blog blg)
        {

                ViewBag.studid = new SelectList(dbstud.students, "studid");
                dbstud.blogs.Add(blg);
                dbstud.SaveChanges();
        }
```

BlogCreate.cshtml

```
@model DemoFFI.Models.blog

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BlogCreate";

}

<h2>BlogCreate</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>blog</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.blogid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.blogid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.blogid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.blogdescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.blogdescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.blogdescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.blogtype, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.blogtype, new List<SelectListItem>
    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "public", Value="public"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "private", Value="private"},
    })

                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.blogtype, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.blogtype, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.studid, "studid", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                 //here get an error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key studid'

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.studid, ViewBag.studid as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.studid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMF0P.png]

**I add a studid referance in another table but it store the null**

[image]

//here get an error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key studid'

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.studid, ViewBag.studid as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: put this line ViewBag.studid = new SelectList(dbstud.students, "studid"); in your get action method rather than post method

Comment: @RahyabAhmed afters ```ViewBag.studid = new SelectList(dbstud.students, "studid", "username");``` add this get method give the same above error   ```@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.studid, ViewBag.studid as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)```

Comment: use this helper to bind your list in your view : @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.studid, new SelectList(ViewBag.studid, "studid", "firstname")) also change this line to
ViewBag.studid = new SelectList(dbstud.students, "studid", "firstname");

Comment: @Rahyab Ahmed  this line generate error ```@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.studid, new SelectList(ViewBag.studid, "studid", "firstname"))``` error is DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'studid'.

Comment: @@Rahyab Ahmed error is studid is not find

Comment: so you can change your `ViewBag.studid = new SelectList(dbstud.students, "studid");` to `ViewBag.studid = dbstud.students.ToList();` in your get action method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215512/discussion-between-rahyab-ahmed-and-raju).